# How to find which currency pairs from a list have both currencies missing in all of the cells in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Suppose you have the following list called `currency_trading_pairs` with the following elements:

```
currency_trading_pairs = ['USD/CAD', 'EUR/USD', 'GBP/USD', 'NZD/USD', 'AUD/USD', 
                          'USD/JPY', 'EUR/CAD', 'EUR/AUD', 'EUR/JPY', 'EUR/GBP',
                          'AUD/CAD', 'GBP/JPY', 'CHF/JPY', 'AUD/JPY', 'AUD/NZD']
```

Now, suppose that you have the following dataframe called `filtered_df` with the following data:

```
    Time    Currency    Volatility expected        Event
24  04:30     GBP   Low Volatility Expected        Inflation Expectations
25  05:00     EUR   High Volatility Expected       EU Leaders Summit  
26  05:10     EUR   Low Volatility Expected        Italian 15-Year BTP Auction
27  05:10     EUR   Low Volatility Expected        Italian 3-Year BTP Auction
28  05:10     EUR   Low Volatility Expected        Italian 7-Year BTP Auction
29  06:00     EUR   Low Volatility Expected        Spanish Consumer Confidence
30  06:30     INR   Low Volatility Expected        Bank Loan Growth
31  06:30     INR   Low Volatility Expected        Deposit Growth
32  06:30     INR   Low Volatility Expected        FX Reserves, USD
33  07:00     INR   Low Volatility Expected        Cumulative Industrial Production (Jan)
34  07:00     INR   Low Volatility Expected        Industrial Production (YoY) (Jan)
35  07:00     INR   Low Volatility Expected        Manufacturing Output (MoM) (Jan)
36  07:00     BRL   Moderate Volatility Expected   CPI (YoY) (Feb)
37  07:00     BRL   Moderate Volatility Expected   CPI (MoM) (Feb)
38  08:06     BRL   Moderate Volatility Expected   Brazilian IPCA Inflation Index SA (MoM)(Feb)
39  08:30     CAD   Low Volatility Expected        Capacity Utilization Rate (Q4)
40  08:30     CAD   High Volatility Expected       Employment Change (Feb)
41  08:30     CAD   Low Volatility Expected        Full Employment Change (Feb)
42  08:30     CAD   Low Volatility Expected        Part Time Employment Change (Feb)
43  08:30     CAD   Low Volatility Expected        Participation Rate (Feb)
44  08:30     CAD   Moderate Volatility Expected   Unemployment Rate (Feb)
```

How could you find which currency pairs (elements) from `currency_trading_pairs` (list) have both currencies missing in all of the cells in the column `Currency` from the `filtered_df` so that you can get the following output in a variable called `the_missing_pairs`:

```
the_missing_pairs = ['NZD/USD', 'AUD/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'CHF/JPY', 'AUD/JPY', 'AUD/NZD']
```

*Further explanation: Basically, assuring that all of the currency names in* `the_missing_pairs` *list do not appear in any of the cells in the column* `Currency` *from the* `filtered_df`.

Comment: Just extract the `Currency` column as a set, and then you  work with list and set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually convert `currency_trading_pairs` to a Series object. Then you can split by `/` and `explode`, then use `isin`, and finally `groupby(level=0)` + `any` to produce the perfect mask:

```
ctp = pd.Series(currency_trading_pairs)
the_missing_pairs = ctp[~ctp.str.split('/').explode().isin(df['Currency']).groupby(level=0).any()].tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> the_missing_pairs
['NZD/USD', 'AUD/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'CHF/JPY', 'AUD/JPY', 'AUD/NZD']
```

Comment: Thank you again!, if you don't mind, may you explain what's the use of `~ctp` and `groupby(level=0).any()` in your second line?

Comment: `~ctp` inverts a mask, so True's become False and False's become True. `groupby(level=0)` takes a Series, and groups all the rows by their index (there will be duplicate indexes because of `explode()`). `.any()` converts each group into a True if that group contains at least 1 True.

Comment: Hey, excuse me for replying again, but I just noticed that the output of `the_missing_pairs` in your code is just the same as `currency_trading_pairs`, can you check again if `ctp[~ctp.str.split('/').explode().isin(df['Currency']).groupby(level=0).any()].tolist()` works as expected? @richardec

Comment: I'm using `Python 3.9.6`, not sure if it doesn't work as expected because of that....

Comment: Actually, it may be due to the fact that the elements in the `Currency` column were added with double space, so for instance, instead of being `EUR` it was `  EUR`.

Comment: Oh yes, thats probably why. The have to be just like the ones you're trying to filter. :)